# How to Sort the Array in Min to Max in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to sort the array in NetLogo. Like this {{array: 22 16 10 7}}

how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Osama, in order to get a more accurate answer from the community, it would be a good idea to include your current code (what you have tried so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array extension doesn't provide for sorting.

Consider using a list instead. Normally in NetLogo we use lists and agentsets for everything; using arrays at all is rare.

But, assuming you really need a sorted array, you could copy the array to a list, sort the list, then make a new array from the result. (Or store the sorted items back into the original array, one at a time.)

Comment: Hi, How can I generate a list of random values like                                                    "set severityLevel random 3" I want a list of random values of severityLevel

Comment: To ask something new, please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using sort-by? I guess that will do the magic.

Comment: yes i did by got this error SORT-BY expected input to be a list or agentset but got the org.nlogo.extensions.array.ArrayExtension$LogoArray {{array: 16 34 16 25}} instead.

Comment: How did you create your array? You should be able to use 'sort [22 16 10 7]'

Comment: my array is created  by using this command array:set tempArray resource_id  round (sqrt(( xcor - xloc ) ^ 2 + (ycor - yloc) ^ 2 ))

Comment: @HappyR that's a list, not an array. normally in NetLogo we use lists for everything, using an array instead is unusual